# Logical operation to highlight text fields

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a scenario here which needs to highlight a field depending on the condition using javascript/html

Let's say if A and B fields are blank, either the C or D field will be required to submit a request and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite understand what you need, can you be more specific? 
What have you tried, can you post somo of your code, for us to understand what uyou really need? 
But far i understood, you want fields A AND B to have values OR C and D (vice versa??), but if A and B don't have any value, C or D must have to continue, right?
Anyway, that .js is understandable, so you can configure it the way you wanted..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="A" type="text">
<input id="B" type="text">
<input id="C" type="text">
<input id="D" type="text">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var Aa, Bb, Cc, Dd;


  Aa = document.getElementById('A').value
  Bb = document.getElementById('B').value
  Cc = document.getElementById('C').value
  Dd = document.getElementById('D').value

  //if A and B fields has values = OK
  if(Aa !== null && Aa !== '' && Bb !== null && Bb !== '') {
   text = "Input OK";
    }
  else if (Cc !== null && Cc !== '' || Dd !== null && Dd !== ''){
   text = "Values A and B are empy, but C  OR D has values";
  }
  else{
   text = "NOT OK: Insert values into A AND B or C OR D"
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes, Here is the code i have written. 

function checkFields(){
 var hasError =  false;
 
    var A = document.forms["form"]["A"];
    var B = document.forms["form"]["B"];
    var C = document.forms["form"]["C"];
    var D = document.forms["form"]["D"];
 
 if( A.value && B.value == ""){
  C.value || D.value is required 
  return true;
  }
 if (C.value && D.value == ""){
  A.value || B.value is required 
  return true; 
 }
return hasError;
}

So the form fields A,B,C,D. If values of A or C  and B or D is blank then one of C or A and D or B value is required to submit.